# Change limit order when bar is closed in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I am using a variable as my limit entry, but the value changed everytime the bar closed. How can I change my limit entry with the price of the last variable value?
I tried this but it seem doesn't work.

```
if (longCondition)
     strategy.order("LONG", strategy.long,1,limit=ht[1])
if ht[1]!=ht[2]
     strategy.cancel_all()
     strategy.order("LONG", strategy.long,1,limit=ht[1])
```

Comment: can you provide more details on your classes?

Comment: The ht is HalfTrend indicator script based on some previos highest and lowest bar.
Or you can simplify it as an EMA.